# Custom Taxonomy is disabled on Edit page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I created a custom taxonomy that it is being used for the **product** post type of woocommerce.

For some reason when you go to the edit screen it is appearing disabled.

This is the code that I'm using to generate the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'mk_restrict_product_by_tag', 0 );
function mk_restrict_product_by_tag() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Restricted Tags',
    'singular_name'              => 'Restricted Tag',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Restricted Tags',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Restricted Tags',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Restricted Tag',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Restricted Tag:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Restricted Tag',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Restricted Tag',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Restricted Tag',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Restricted Tag',
    'view_item'                  => 'View Restricted Tag',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Restricted Tags with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Restricted Tags',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
    'popular_items'              => 'Popular Restricted Tags',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Restricted Tags',
    'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
    'no_terms'                   => 'No Restricted Tags',
    'items_list'                 => 'Restricted Tags list',
    'items_list_navigation'      => 'Restricted Tags list navigation'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => false,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
    'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    'rewrite'                    => false,
    'show_in_quick_edit'         => true,
    'capabilities' =>
            array (
              'manage_terms' => 'manage_categories',
              'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories',
              'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
              'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts',
            )
);
register_taxonomy( 'mk_restricted_tag', array('user','product'), $args );
}
```

The HTML that WordPress is generating:

```
    <div id="tagsdiv-mk_restricted_tag" class="postbox " >
    <button type="button" class="handlediv button-link" aria-expanded="true"><span class="screen-reader-text">Toggle panel: Restricted Tags</span><span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    <h2 class='hndle'><span>Restricted Tags</span></h2>
    <div class="inside">
        <div class="tagsdiv" id="mk_restricted_tag">
            <div class="jaxtag">
                <div class="nojs-tags hide-if-js">
                    <label for="tax-input-mk_restricted_tag">Add or remove Restricted Tags</label>
                    <p><textarea name="tax_input[mk_restricted_tag]" rows="3" cols="20" class="the-tags" id="tax-input-mk_restricted_tag"  disabled='disabled' aria-describedby="new-tag-mk_restricted_tag-desc"></textarea></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tagchecklist"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the text area is Disabled. If I convert the taxonomy to hierarchical the checboxes are disabled (and I do get to see the terms).

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you logged-in as admin ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I had the members plugin installed and it was overwriting some permissions by giving priority to denied options.